# Excel VBA - Delete file from sharepoint bypassing confirmation

Tags: excel, xml, vba, http, automation

I want to delete a file from my sharepoint folder. When I try to do it manually, it gives me a warning: "It looks like someone has the file open. Delete anyway?". I believe this is why it's not deleting the file. I made sure the to-be-deleted file is not open at all, so not sure why I'm still getting asked. Can this be bypassed?

I get a Status 405 error. (via `objXML.Status`)

```
Sub deleteFile()
    Dim spName As String
    Dim objXML As Object
    
    spName = "https://xyzplace.sharepoint.com/sites/GroupA/Shared%20Documents/FolderA/example_file.xlsx"
    
    Set objXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        objXML.Open "DELETE", spNAME, False
        objXML.Send
    
    Set objXML = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: [Application.DisplayAlerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayalerts) may help

Comment: The warning is not within Excel. It's when I go to the sharepoint site, right click the file manually and select delete. It'll come up with a warning box in the top right saying "1 item wasn't deleted from FolderA. It looks like someone has the open. Delete anyway?" Then I can choose to click delete or press x to close.